# How to make DateTime Primary Key Plus Auto Increment

Tags: mysql

Hello I have a table in my database which is going to be filled by customers online and

each record of them must be saved uniquely so i want to have a primary key in my table which

take its value from Data and Time, i m using MySQL its making the primary key Date Time but

**NOT Auto Increment how can i make it Auto Increment.**

Per day i have 100 records if Data&Time is not working , so i don't want to start from 1,2,3,4...

So if Data&Time is not working, please suggest some way for me to start from like 0000001,

0000002, 0000003...........................

Waiting For your suggest dears.....

Answer (score 0):

You can make column auto increment while creating table and then apply starting value of auto-increment field.

```
CREATE TABLE tableName(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                        ..rest of columns... 
                       );
```

Then specify starting value

```
ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT=1000000;
```

So now you will have records inserted generating values starting from 1000000 , then 1000001,1000002 .. and so on.

Padding zeroes to get 0000001 , 0000002 will require you to track number of digits of id value generated which looks like needless extra work.

If you to make existing column as AUTO_INCREMENT do this

```
ALTER TABLE tableName MODIFY tableNameID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

After that Do

```
ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT=1000000;
```

Comment: can i used Date&Time as its value

Comment: No you should not use Timestamp as primary key .. it will work ok if records are inserted one by one seperately but will fail when more than one record is inserted at sametime becuse timestamp value generated will be same for both the records nad will violate primary key constraint... Use integer autoincrement , beside being unique they are extremely good for JOINS with other tables..

Comment: this is also not working ALTER TABLE student

`EmpID` NOT NULL 

 AUTO INCREMENT=1000000;

Comment: You will have to add auto increment property and specify starting value seperately